# Setting the position of a path

Tags: android, canvas, path

Is there a way to set the position of a path object directly? Without translating or offsetting, just directly setting it's position.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `android.graphics.Path`, you can use `moveTo(x, y)`.

---

Two center around a given point, you could get the bounds with `computeBounds` and then `offeset` the path based on the center of the bounds and the original starting position

Comment: Does that set the position directly though?

Comment: If you call `moveTo(100, 100)` then the next part of the path will start from the (100,100) location, I'm sure what are you looking for...

Comment: Sorry. To be more clear I already have a path, I want to move it's center point to a given coordinate on the canvas. As an example, it would be something like path.setPosition(x,y).

Comment: I want to set it directly without offsetting, moveTo, transforming or anything. Just directly setting the position.

Comment: I think you are talking about centering around a point (x, y), this is not supported (= you need to write it your self). These are all the supported operations: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html

Comment: You could calculate the center from `computeBounds`